# Can't receive UDP broadcast with python on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, works on Raspbian & Centos on same network

Tags: networking, 20.04, python

I've got a device on my LAN that is sending broadcast packets on UDP 50222. Using tcpdump, I can see the packets, but in python on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS box no data is received. However, on 2 other systems on the same LAN (Centos 7.8 and Raspbian 9 [stretch]) the exact same code works. This doesn't seem to be entirely limited to python; running **nc -lu 50222** on the two non-Ubuntu systems works, but no data is received on the Ubuntu box.

Here's some code I've used to test this:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP) # UDP
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
client.bind(("", 50222))
while True:
    data, addr = client.recvfrom(1024)
    print("received message: %s"%data)
```

I believe the two calls to setsockopt() aren't actually needed, but I've tried both with and without them and it makes no difference on any of the machines.

I've tried running both the sample code as well as netcat under sudo but that makes no difference. Looking at the tcpdump captures in Wireshark, the packets contain the data I expect, and the checksums are correct.

Searching here and elsewhere, the most common issue I've seen is not doing the bind correctly, but I believe that what I've used is correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: works fine for me. Ubuntu server 20.04.1.

Comment: do you have any firewall rules that might block the port? ufw or iptables?

Comment: It did turn out to be ufw. I wasn't seeing anything in the logs, but changing the rule to allow all traffic from the LAN fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to a firewall that was blocking most local traffic with certain exceptions (e.g., ssh). The firewall was modified to allow the broadcast traffic and that resolved the problem.

Specifically, the ufw firewall was previously configured to only allow specified ports from hosts on the LAN (e.g., 80, 443, 53, 22) and drop all other traffic.

To fix the issue, I ran the following command:

`sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24` where 192.168.0.0/24 is my local network.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the details you've mentioned. I hope this is more useful.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅.

Comment: Apparently I've still got one more hour to wait, but will do so.